# SCREEN: Permissions and security

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I was just looking for some clarification on the screen command and permissions:

I ran this command to allow the user to view their detached screen. Otherwise the user could not view their detached screen:

```
sudo chmod o+rw /dev/pts/1
```

However, does this mean that another non root user can view their detached screen(s)?

Essentially I just want to make sure that no other non root user can view the users' detached screen.

Also how does screen decide to use `/dev/pts/1`, `/dev/pts/2`, `/dev/pts/3`, etc.?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm unsure what you are trying to do, every user can issue `screen -ls` and `screen -r` for screens they created.

Answer (score 1):

I have started using tmux instead as It works much better thank SCREEN which is a little old now.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92824/tmux-equivalent-command-to-screen-d-m-s-session-name